# How to connect IntelliJ IDEA with a free Jira instance?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jira, jetbrains-ide

My team has a Jira project on Atlassian servers. How can I connect that project with IntelliJ IDEA IDE?

When creating a connection from IntelliJ to Atlassian, I need the server name and username with credentials.

What is in this case the value of the Server URL?

Here is my error log:

```
com.atlassian.theplugin.commons.remoteapi.RemoteApiException: my_username:[password XX chars]@https://instance.atlassian.net

Login failed
    at com.atlassian.connector.commons.jira.rest.JiraRestSessionImpl.wrapWithRemoteApiException(JiraRestSessionImpl.java:800)
    at com.atlassian.connector.commons.jira.rest.JiraRestSessionImpl.login(JiraRestSessionImpl.java:180)
    at com.atlassian.connector.commons.jira.rest.JiraRestSessionImpl.testConnection(JiraRestSessionImpl.java:762)
    at com.atlassian.connector.commons.jira.JiraRESTFacade2Impl.testServerConnection(JiraRESTFacade2Impl.java:329)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.atlassian.connector.commons.jira.JIRAServerFacade2Impl$1.invoke(JIRAServerFacade2Impl.java:91)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.testServerConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.atlassian.connector.commons.jira.JIRAServerFacade2Impl.testServerConnection(JIRAServerFacade2Impl.java:268)
    at com.atlassian.theplugin.commons.jira.IntelliJJiraServerFacade.testServerConnection(IntelliJJiraServerFacade.java:473)
    at com.atlassian.theplugin.idea.config.serverconfig.ProductConnector.connect(ProductConnector.java:35)
    at com.atlassian.theplugin.ConnectionWrapper.run(ConnectionWrapper.java:63)
Caused by: com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.RestClientException: Login failed
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:82)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.postAndParse(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:140)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseySessionRestClient.login(JerseySessionRestClient.java:54)
    at com.atlassian.connector.commons.jira.rest.JiraRestSessionImpl.wrapWithRemoteApiException(JiraRestSessionImpl.java:797)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 401
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:607)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:507)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient$4.call(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:144)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:68)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: You use some plugin to connect IntelliJ with Jira ?

Comment: @AntonDozortsev I have IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.2.5 with Atlassian Connector.

Answer (score 8):

For everyone looking how to connect JIRA without the Atlassian Connector, there is already a simple build-in solution in IntelliJ IDEA:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Tasks Server Settings]

Normally you don't have to edit the "Search".

And it's also available via the top menu `"Tools" -> "Tasks & Contexts" -> "Configure Servers..."`

Comment: Seems like a good solution, but I get the error that assignee field either doesn't exist or is not visible for anonymous users. The field does exist and I thought the user and password would be used to log in to the server.

Comment: If I remove the search query it says it can connect, but then when I try to look for a task I get the same error, only with the summary field.

Comment: Apparently regular username+password authentication doesn't work at the moment (idea 2019.1). Instead of the password you need to use an API token which can be created at https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens

Comment: @Samuel Password still works for me in IDEA 2019.2.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the url by login into your Jira account via a browser; the Server URL is the the first section of the URL before the '/'.

Example:

https://example.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Server URL = https://example.atlassian.net

**Update:**

Also note that Atlassian has stopped support for IDE Connectors since 20 April 2015, developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/06/… ,so I would consider rather connecting your IntelliJ to Jira thorugh other means, such as GitHub via WebHooks

Comment: Ok, in my case example is 'instance'. So, when I type my credentials it says Failed Login, but credentials are good.

Comment: Is the screen you trying to fill out look like this:
[Atlassian Connector IntelliJ Screen](https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/148767098/servers-configuration.png?version=1&modificationDate=1324302205365&api=v2)

Comment: Very similar, yes.

Comment: @Aleksandar Can you post the Failed Login error log here? (i.e. in the "Show Details" section on the pop-up)

Comment: @Aleksandar Also note that Atlassian has stopped support for IDE Connectors since 20 April 2015, https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/06/discontinuing-ide-connectors-support/ ,so I would consider rather connecting your IntelliJ to Jira thorugh other means, such as GitHub via WebHooks

Answer (score 0):

Server url is something like: https://aleksandar.atlassian.net
[image]